# Flink:How to get the value after union other datastream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

eg.

I have two `DataStream<Tuple4<String, String, Date, String>>` named ds1 and ds2, `DataStream ds3 = ds1.union(ds2)`.Then I want to know How can I get the value of `ds1.f2` and `ds2.f2` from ds3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream union in Flink is the same as the union operation on multisets -- you just get a bigger stream will all of the elements from the two input streams.

So, in other words, a Union is not a Join. ds3.f2 is a value that previously was either ds1.f2 or ds2.f2 for some Tuple in one of those streams.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could add a fifth element to each Tuple so you would know its origin. Or you might rather use some sort of Join operation to combine the two streams. See the documentation for [window joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/#datastream-transformations), [table joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/tableApi.html#joins), [sql joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/sql.html#joins), and [low-level joins](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html#low-level-joins).